# Order interfaces by key

Tags: go

I looked for a way to order one interface by key in Golang and print the concatenated values.
Because I couldn't find any solution I will share mine.
Please feel free to share a better solution.

Imagine that we have a `struct` and we want to print the values ordered by key.

```
type Point struct {
    X string
    Y string
    A string
    C string
}

var result interface{} = Point{"1", "2", "4", "5"}
```

The expected result should be `4512`

My solution is:

```
func sortStructures(structure interface{}) string {
    var result string
    v := reflect.ValueOf(structure)

    //Add all the key of a struct to a array
    values := make([]string, v.NumField())
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        values[i] = v.Type().Field(i).Name
    }

    //Sort the keys of the structure
    sort.Strings(values)

    //Concat the values of the ordered keys
    for j := 0; j < len(values); j++ {
        result += v.FieldByName(values[j]).String()
    }

    return result
}
```

Please note the in my case I needed to get the concatenated string of the values, but I think that with this example you can modify and use for other outputs.

I would like to ask if there is a more efficient way to do it?

Example: [Go Play](https://play.golang.org/p/wFwBzzypuC)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30915092/6452829) you can find a proper answer to your post, with IMHO a better solution.

Comment: Wouldn't you always know what exported fields you have, since go is pretty strongly typed?

Comment: @biosckon the function `sortStructures` accepts interfaces, so accepts all kind of structures. I needed this function to order independently of the structure.